# ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)) fails in Afxwin2.inl

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, application-verifier

I am creating a view in my project which is a child class of CView.

```
class CBaseGLView : public CView
```

In oncreate function I am checking it null or not as below:

```
int CBaseGLView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
            return -1;

    m_hWnd = GetSafeHwnd();
    if( ::IsWindow(m_hWnd)== NULL)
    {
            return 1;
    }
    m_pCDC= new CClientDC(this);
    m_hDC = m_pCDC->GetSafeHdc();

    if (SetWindowPixelFormat()==FALSE)
            return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am debugging with ApplicationVerifier I am getting a debug assertion in below lines in afxwin2.inl:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE LRESULT CWnd::_AFX_FUNCNAME(SendMessage)(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) const

{ ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); }
```

And also `m_hwnd` is shown as `unused 0` with the memory address of `0x00170fd6`.
Given below is the output from Application verifier.

```
VERIFIER STOP 00000013: pid 0xDF4: First chance access violation for current stack trace. 

339F9020 : Invalid address causing the exception.
0109D75E : Code address executing the invalid access.
0018E034 : Exception record.
0018E084 : Context record.
```

Following is the call stack of the debug build. It is too long, sorry for that.

```
ntdll.dll!7729000c()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
vrfcore.dll!VfCoreRedirectedStopMessage(unsigned long Code=19, char * Message=0x73341b5c, unsigned long Param1=444756000, char * Description1=0x73341b94, unsigned long Param2=17422174, char * Description2=0x73341bb4, unsigned long Param3=1630260, char * Description3=0x73341bd4, unsigned long Param4=1630340, char * Description4=0x73341c00)  Line 103 + 0x19 bytes C++
vfbasics.dll!VerifierStopMessage(unsigned long Code=19, char * Message=0x73341b5c, unsigned long Param1=444756000, char * Description1=0x73341b94, unsigned long Param2=17422174, char * Description2=0x73341bb4, unsigned long Param3=1630260, char * Description3=0x73341bd4, unsigned long Param4=1630340, char * Description4=0x73341c00)  Line 1214    C
vfbasics.dll!AVrfpCheckFirstChanceException(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionPointers=0x0018df7c)  Line 1108 + 0x2b bytes C
vfbasics.dll!AVrfpVectoredExceptionHandler(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionPointers=0x0018df7c)  Line 323    C
ntdll.dll!772f62de()    
ntdll.dll!772db652()    
ntdll.dll!772db314()    
ntdll.dll!77290133()    
user32.dll!753a617a()   

Axial.exe!CWnd::SendMessageA(unsigned int message=2125, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 42 + 0x44 bytes C++
Axial.exe!SECWorkbookClientWnd::OnMDISetMenu(unsigned int wParam=261688291, long lParam=21302363)  Line 390 C++
Axial.exe!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=560, unsigned int wParam=261688291, long lParam=21302363, long * pResult=0x0018e980)  Line 2018 + 0x11 bytes  C++
Axial.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=560, unsigned int wParam=261688291, long lParam=21302363)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes   C++
Axial.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x1a54bf98, HWND__ * hWnd=0x00120ff0, unsigned int nMsg=560, unsigned int wParam=261688291, long lParam=21302363)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes   C++
Axial.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x00120ff0, unsigned int nMsg=560, unsigned int wParam=261688291, long lParam=21302363)  Line 403    C++
user32.dll!753962fa()   
user32.dll!75397316()   
user32.dll!75396ce9()   
user32.dll!75396de8()   
user32.dll!75396e44()   
ntdll.dll!7729010a()    
user32.dll!753972b9()   
user32.dll!753a2161()   
user32.dll!753a0f91()   
user32.dll!753a9deb()   
user32.dll!753a9dfd()   
user32.dll!753a8124()   
Axial.exe!CMDIChildWnd::DefWindowProcA(unsigned int nMsg=34, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 429    C++
Axial.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=34, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 1756 + 0x1c bytes   C++
Axial.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x1a826f08, HWND__ * hWnd=0x00210bbe, unsigned int nMsg=34, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes   C++
Axial.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x00210bbe, unsigned int nMsg=34, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 403    C++
user32.dll!753962fa()   
user32.dll!75396d3a()   
user32.dll!75396ce9()   
user32.dll!75396de8()   
user32.dll!75396e44()   
ntdll.dll!7729010a()    
user32.dll!75398e63()   
user32.dll!753a7b51()   
Axial.exe!CFrameWnd::BringToTop(int nCmdShow=1)  Line 2362  C++
Axial.exe!CFrameWnd::ActivateFrame(int nCmdShow=1)  Line 2341   C++
Axial.exe!CMDIChildWnd::ActivateFrame(int nCmdShow=-1)  Line 762    C++
Axial.exe!CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame(CDocument * pDoc=0x1a6a2de8, int bMakeVisible=1)  Line 814  C++
Axial.exe!CDocTemplate::InitialUpdateFrame(CFrameWnd * pFrame=0x1a826f08, CDocument * pDoc=0x1a6a2de8, int bMakeVisible=1)  Line 330    C++
Axial.exe!CMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(const char * lpszPathName=0x0018f6fc, int bMakeVisible=1)  Line 166   C++
Axial.exe!CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(const char * lpszFileName=0x19418fa0)  Line 986 C++
Axial.exe!CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile(const char * lpszFileName=0x19418fa0)  Line 84  C++
Axial.exe!CAxialApp::OpenDocumentFile(const char * lpszFileName=0x19418fa0)  Line 983 + 0xc bytes   C++
Axial.exe!CWinApp::OnOpenRecentFile(unsigned int nID=57616)  Line 132 + 0x2a bytes  C++
Axial.exe!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg(CCmdTarget * pTarget=0x018e6e88, unsigned int nID=57616, int nCode=0, void (void)* pfn=0x009f8140, void * pExtra=0x00000000, unsigned int nSig=60, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 101 + 0xa bytes C++
Axial.exe!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57616, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 381 + 0x27 bytes  C++
Axial.exe!CAxialApp::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int id=57616, int code=0, void * extra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * handler=0x00000000)  Line 1135 + 0x40 bytes  C++
Axial.exe!CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57616, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 951 + 0x23 bytes   C++
Axial.exe!SECMDIFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57616, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 2270  C++
Axial.exe!CWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 2364  C++
Axial.exe!CFrameWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 366  C++
Axial.exe!SECMDIFrameWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 2214 + 0x10 bytes   C++
Axial.exe!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0, long * pResult=0x0018fc68)  Line 1769 + 0x1e bytes C++
Axial.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes  C++
Axial.exe!SECMDIFrameWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 2685 + 0x14 bytes    C++
Axial.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x1a4acf78, HWND__ * hWnd=0x0005102a, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes  C++
Axial.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x0005102a, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=57616, long lParam=0)  Line 403   C++
user32.dll!753962fa()   
user32.dll!75396d3a()   
user32.dll!75396ce9()   
user32.dll!753977c4()   
user32.dll!75397bca()   
Axial.exe!AfxInternalPumpMessage()  Line 183    C++
Axial.exe!CWinThread::PumpMessage()  Line 900   C++
Axial.exe!CWinThread::Run()  Line 629 + 0xd bytes   C++
Axial.exe!CWinApp::Run()  Line 896  C++
Axial.exe!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00400000, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance=0x00000000, char * lpCmdLine=0x07e78ffd, int nCmdShow=1)  Line 47 + 0xd bytes  C++
Axial.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00400000, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance=0x00000000, char * lpCmdLine=0x07e78ffd, int nCmdShow=1)  Line 34 C++
Axial.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 263 + 0x2c bytes    C
Axial.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()  Line 182 C
kernel32.dll!768033aa()     
ntdll.dll!772b9ef2()    
ntdll.dll!772b9ec5()
```

Your help is greately appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is `SECWorkbookClientWnd::OnMDISetMenu`. You're probably calling a function that is trying to send a message to a CWnd that is not yet created/attached.

Comment: Thanks for the answer snowdude. I have updated the question with the call stack of debug build.

Comment: thanks, I the source file is not shown for "SECWorkbookClientWnd::OnMDISetMenu". Anyway I will try to find from where it goes there.